# Multiple select not highlighting items

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have added select all button to multiple select. Problem is that all the items are getting selected but not getting highlighted if I click on select all button.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="label_hd">Profiles* {{user.profile}}
    <input type="button" id="select_all" ng-click="selectedAll()"
           name="select_all" value="Select All" style="margin-left: 10px">
</div>
<select multiple class="browser-default" name="userprofile"
        id="userprofile" ng-model="user.profile">
    <option ng-repeat="profile in userprofiles" value="{{profile.profile}}">
        {{ profile.profile_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Controller.js code:

```
$scope.selectedAll = function(){
    $scope.user.profile = []; 
    angular.forEach($scope.userprofiles, function(item){
       $scope.user.profile.push( item.profile);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: can you provide a live example?

Comment: You need to add one additional flag for each profile in userprofiles and based on that flag whether true or false, you can use ng-class to toggle background color.

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi Tried that but it's not working

Comment: Can u provide example?

Comment: @Saniyasyedqureshi I found the solution. Need to set $scope.user.profile[item] = true;

Comment: If you solved the problem, either delete the question or answer the question. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Answer (score -1):

Need to set $scope.user.profile[item] = true;

```
$scope.selectedAll = function(){
$scope.user.profile = []; 
angular.forEach($scope.userprofiles, function(item){
    $scope.user.profile.push( item.profile.toString());
    $scope.user.profile[item] = true;
}); 
}
```